# How to prevent the "/r/n" sequence when Enter key is pressed on a Textbox - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, enter

I have a `EditableTextBlock` which implements the editing in-line approach.
Currently, when `EditName = true`, it selects all the containing `Text` from the `TextBox` and starts the edit mode. The problem is, if I hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, it saves a blank name to my item.

After debugging the code, I noticed that when I press <kbd>enter</kbd>, this command is translated to a `"/r/n"` string, replacing the selected text. And then my code line below just turn it an empty string:

```
_textBox.Text.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
```

What I would like is **to prevent the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key from passing this value and erase all my selected text**. Not-selecting the text in the first place wouldn't solve my problem, as this is a desired functionality.
Is it even possible? Thanks in advance!

Below are some code that might help you guys understand my circumstances:

**`EditableTextBlock.cs`**

```
 public class EditableTextBlock : TextBlock
    {
        public bool IsInEditMode
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)GetValue(IsInEditModeProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(IsInEditModeProperty, value);
            }
        }

        private EditableTextBlockAdorner _adorner;

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsInEditMode.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsInEditModeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsInEditMode", typeof(bool), typeof(EditableTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsInEditModeUpdate));

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether [is in edit mode update] [the specified obj].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The obj.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private static void IsInEditModeUpdate(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            EditableTextBlock textBlock = obj as EditableTextBlock;
            if (null != textBlock)
            {
                //Get the adorner layer of the uielement (here TextBlock)
                AdornerLayer layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(textBlock);

                //If the IsInEditMode set to true means the user has enabled the edit mode then
                //add the adorner to the adorner layer of the TextBlock.
                if (textBlock.IsInEditMode)
                {
                    if (null == textBlock._adorner)
                    {
                        textBlock._adorner = new EditableTextBlockAdorner(textBlock); 

                        //Events wired to exit edit mode when the user presses Enter key or leaves the control.
                        textBlock._adorner.TextBoxKeyUp += textBlock.TextBoxKeyUp;
                        textBlock._adorner.TextBoxLostFocus += textBlock.TextBoxLostFocus;
                    }
                    layer.Add(textBlock._adorner);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (layer != null)
                    {
                        //Remove the adorner from the adorner layer.
                        Adorner[] adorners = layer.GetAdorners(textBlock);
                        if (adorners != null)
                        {
                            foreach (Adorner adorner in adorners)
                            {
                                if (adorner is EditableTextBlockAdorner)
                                {
                                    layer.Remove(adorner);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Update the textblock's text binding.
                    BindingExpression expression = textBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextProperty);
                    if (null != expression)
                    {
                        expression.UpdateTarget();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the length of the max.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The length of the max.</value>
        public int MaxLength
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)GetValue(MaxLengthProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(MaxLengthProperty, value);
            }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MaxLength.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxLengthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MaxLength", typeof(int), typeof(EditableTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));

        private void TextBoxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsInEditMode = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// release the edit mode when user presses enter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void TextBoxKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                IsInEditMode = false;
            }

            TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
            if (tb.Text.EndsWith("..") && e.Key == Key.OemPeriod)
            {
                tb.Text = tb.Text.Replace("..", ".");
                tb.CaretIndex = tb.Text.Length;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when an unhandled <see cref="E:System.Windows.Input.Mouse.MouseDown"/> attached event reaches an element in its route that is derived from this class. Implement this method to add class handling for this event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="T:System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs"/> that contains the event data. This event data reports details about the mouse button that was pressed and the handled state.</param>
        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            /*if (e.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                IsInEditMode = true;
            }
            else if (e.ClickCount == 2)
            {
                IsInEditMode = true;
            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

**`EditableTextBlockAdorner.cs`**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Adorner class which shows textbox over the text block when the Edit mode is on.
    /// </summary>
    public class EditableTextBlockAdorner : Adorner
    {
        private readonly VisualCollection _collection;

        private readonly TextBox _textBox;

        private readonly TextBlock _textBlock;

        public EditableTextBlockAdorner(EditableTextBlock adornedElement)
            : base(adornedElement)
        {
            _collection = new VisualCollection(this);
            _textBox = new TextBox();
            _textBlock = adornedElement;
            Binding binding = new Binding("Text") {Source = adornedElement};
            _textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
            _textBox.SelectAll();
            _textBox.AcceptsReturn = true;
            _textBox.MaxLength = adornedElement.MaxLength;
            _textBox.KeyUp += _textBox_KeyUp;
            _collection.Add(_textBox);
        }

        void _textBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                _textBox.Text = _textBox.Text.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
                BindingExpression expression = _textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
                if (null != expression)
                {
                    expression.UpdateSource();
                }
            }
        }

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            return _collection[index];
        }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount
        {
            get
            {
                return _collection.Count;
            }
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            _textBox.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, _textBlock.DesiredSize.Width + 50, _textBlock.DesiredSize.Height * 1.5));
            _textBox.Focus();
            return finalSize;
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(null, new Pen
                                                   {
                Brush = Brushes.Gold,
                Thickness = 2
            }, new Rect(0, 0, _textBlock.DesiredSize.Width + 50, _textBlock.DesiredSize.Height * 1.5));
        }

        public event RoutedEventHandler TextBoxLostFocus
        {
            add
            {
                _textBox.LostFocus += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                _textBox.LostFocus -= value;
            }
        }

        public event KeyEventHandler TextBoxKeyUp
        {
            add
            {
                _textBox.KeyUp += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                _textBox.KeyUp -= value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML usage:

```
<ctrl:EditableTextBlock Margin="6,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsInEditMode="{Binding EditName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple and easy, how did I miss that?!:

```
_textBox.AcceptsReturn = false;
```